Several subdivided bibliographies in each chapter
I would like to write a document with several chapters, and where each chapter has its own subdivided bibliography at its end. In other words, I would like a subdivided bibliography at the end of each chapter (not just one bibliography by chapter). It is therefore quite possible for a reference to be cited in several different chapters.
Until now, I've been using multibib, but I've just realized that there seems to be a bug in this extension.
Visually, I get what I want, but all occurrences of a citation refer to the first time it appears in a bibliography, when clicked on.
I'm having trouble seeing if this is possible to achieve with biblatex. What do you think?
Here, a concrete example:

File test.tex:

\documentclass[a4paper,french]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{sek}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{sekbis}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{prim}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primbis}

\newcommand*{\citeprim}[2][]{\addtocategory{prim}{#2}\cite[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand*{\citeprimbis}[2][]{\addtocategory{primbis}{#2}\cite[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand*{\citesek}[2][]{\addtocategory{sek}{#2}\cite[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand*{\citesekbis}[2][]{\addtocategory{sekbis}{#2}\cite[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Prim}

        \citeprim{Demoule2009}

        \citeprimbis{leroi-gourhan2005}

        \citeprimbis{gaucher2005}

        \citeprim{besse2014}

        \printbibliography[category=prim, title=Toto] 
        \printbibliography[category=primbis, title=Titi]

\chapter{sek}

        \citesekbis{besse2014}
        
        \citesek{gaucher2005}

        \printbibliography[title=Tutu,category=sek]
        \printbibliography[title=Tata, category=sekbis]

\end{document}


File test.bib:

@article{besse2014,
Author = {Besse, Marie},
Journal = {La Recherche},
Number = {484},
Pages = {42--46},
Title = {Il y a 5000 ans, une mystérieuse unité européenne},
Date = {2014-02},
Url = {https://www.academia.edu/},
Urldate = {2014-06-09}
}
@book{leroi-gourhan2005,
title = {Dictionnaire de la Préhistoire},
editor = {Leroi-Gourhan, André},
publisher = {Presses universitaires de France},
year = {2005},
address = {Paris},
pagetotal = {1277},
series = {Quadrige}
}
@inbook{gaucher2005,
title = {L'Âge du bronze},
author = {Gaucher, Gilles},
booktitle = {Dictionnaire de la Préhistoire},
editor = {Leroi-Gourhan, André"},
publisher = {Presses universitaires de France},
year = {2005},
address = {Paris},
series = {Quadrige},
pages = {577--578}
}
@proceedings{Demoule2009,
Editor = {Demoule, Jean-Paul and Landes, Christian},
Eventdate = {2008-02-14/2008-02-15},
Eventtitle = {Actes du colloque \enquote{La fabrique de
l'archéologie en France}},
Location = {Paris},
Pagetotal = {301},
Publisher = {La Découverte},
Title = {La fabrique de l'archéologie en France},
Venue = {Paris},
Year = {2009}
}


Compilation process:


pdflatex test.tex
biber test
pdflatex test.tex
pdflatex test.tex

Problem: If I click on the reference [besse2014] or [gaucher2005] in chapter sek, then I go to the bibliography of chapter Prim because these references are also mentioned in the chapter Prim.
